# Send Notification as message with Firebase Cloud Messaging in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a Chat App. When the app enters background and if he receives a message, then a notification must appear.

What I understand is that FIRMessaging.sendMessage() sends something to the cloud. But how the other device is gonna receive it ? It cant be continually looking for messages that are targetted to him...

I would like to understand how to use this fonction and what are the parameters to pass in it. So far and with the current documentation, I couldnt do it.

```
[[FIRMessaging message]sendMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary *)message
                                to:(nonnull NSString *)receiver
                     withMessageID:(nonnull NSString *)messageID
                        timeToLive:(int64_t)ttl;
```

What should I put in the receiver ? It's userId in firebase ? or what ?
In the exemples they talk about `SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com"`

which confuses me cause it looks like it's either my Id or the Id of the firebase App..

I cant even figure out if i'm trying to send an upstream or downstream message (dont understand)

Well all I can say is that I really get my head around it...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/upstream#handle_upstream_message_callbacks_1

Thanks!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Comment: Hi Morales, I edited my question, is it more specific? I mean really i'm lost. I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: The method you linked is meant to be called by your app server to send a message to a device (known as a downstream message). Note that these concepts haven't changed from Google Cloud Messaging, so following a tutorial for GCM might still be helpful to get your bearings.

Comment: Ok ! i'm going to search a tutorial for GCM. Any idea where i could find that ?

Answer (score -1):

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) and [Firebase Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) (which is built on Firebase Cloud Messaging) handle this automatically for you. From the documentation of Firebase Notifications:

> When your app is in the background on a user's device, notifications are delivered to the system tray. When a user taps on the notification, the app launcher opens your app. If you want, you can also add client message handling to receive notifications in your app when it is already in the foreground on the user's device.

Comment: Hello Frank, could you help me understanding this "sendMessage" function as stated in my question ? Thanks a lot for your help !